# Read the x and y components of the pixel gradient of an image using itk

Tags: filter, gradient, itk

I want to read the x and y components of the pixel gradient of an image within an extended template class that preexists in ITK. Specifically i use a GradientImageFilter:

```
typedef    GradientImageFilter<  FixedImageType,   float>    FixedGradient;
```

Then i use the following types:

```
typedef CovariantVector< float, 2  >   VectorPixelType;
typedef Image< VectorPixelType, 2  >   VectorImageType;
```

in order to define the following image adaptor:

```
typedef ImageAdaptor<  VectorImageType, VectorPixelAccessor> ImageAdaptorTypeFX;


VectorPixelAccessor  accessorFX, accessorFY, accessorMX, accessorMY;
```

/*FixedImage X gradient*/
    ImageAdaptorTypeFX::Pointer adaptorFX = ImageAdaptorTypeFX::New();

```
accessorFX.SetIndex(0);
adaptorFX->SetPixelAccessor(accessorFX);
FixedGradient::Pointer f = FixedGradient::New();

f->SetInput(this->GetFixedImage());

f->Update();


adaptorFX->SetImage(f->GetOutput());

typedef Image< float, 2 >   OutputImageType;
typedef RescaleIntensityImageFilter< ImageAdaptorTypeFX, FixedImageType>      RescalerType;
RescalerType::Pointer rescaler = RescalerType::New();






rescaler->SetOutputMinimum(0);
rescaler->SetOutputMaximum(1);
rescaler->SetInput(adaptorFX);

rescaler->Update();
```

But when i try to have an access at the component of the rescaler all a get is zero for all pixels. Why is this happening? By the way can a image filter be used for 3D image files?

Comment: I hate when other people do this to me, specially when I'm learning a new technology but I guess I have to ask: Why are you using adaptors? Whay do you want to achieve? I remember my struggles with ITK, so let's try to work your example together

Comment: Other thing about your question @Spanakis, StackOverflow is a Q&A site, is not a forum, the difference is that you must ask the questions in order to make the useful for other people and not only for your self. so when you said " Why is this happening? By the way can a image filter be used for 3D image files?" Is *two* questions instead of one. Only one question for post is desired. This will improve your reputation and with it your chances to get help :)